# Apply Function to multiple vectors/lists R

Tags: r, list, function, apply

I made a function `g` to calculate maximum likelihood following a multivariated normal distribution in order to classify the rows of a data frame `test` between 34 classes. So I need to use this function over a data frame and with several different set of parameters. My code works but it's to slow. I want to get it faster, maybe by removing the `for` loop and using some other apply's family function (which I don't have any experience).

```
g = function(x,p,mu,Sigma){
    log(p) - log(det(Sigma)) - as.matrix(x-mu)%*%solve(Sigma)%*%t(as.matrix(x-mu))
}

mu = summaryBy(.~class,train,FUN=mean)

Sigma = by(train[,1:8],train$class,cov)

p = as.data.frame(table(train$class))
p$Freq = p$Freq/n

k = length(levels(train$class))

logver = NULL

for(j in 1:k){
   logver = cbind(logver,apply(test,1,g,p=p$Freq[j],mu=mu[j,-1],Sigma=Sigma[[j]]))
}

preds = apply(logver,1,which.max)
```

The output `logver` must be a data frame with one row for each row of test and one col for each j, so in this case with 340000 rows and 34 cols.

`p$Freq` is a numeric vector 1x34. `mu` is a data frame 34x9 (fist col is a factor generated by summaryBy mean). `Sigma` is a list with 34 elements and each element is a 8x8 covariace matrix. `test` is a data frame 340000x8.

```
head(test)
  band1  band2  band3  band4   band5   band6   band7   band9
1 2.0592 4.3630 6.6506 10.5952 18.4566 37.3683 36.9154 33.9467
2 2.5772 4.0766 6.0116 10.1476 18.8585 36.7654 36.2221 33.3717
3 2.8240 4.0766 6.4183  9.6813 18.5148 37.3113 35.7318 33.8367
4 2.8999 4.4317 7.4529 10.2842 18.4566 37.2513 37.3219 33.8367
5 2.8684 3.5324 7.5845 10.9021 19.2262 37.4758 36.0219 33.3472
6 2.4069 4.3256 6.0241 10.6668 20.0381 36.7203 36.4816 33.3472

head(train)
  band1  band2  band3   band4   band5   band6   band7   band9   class
1 5.1224 8.1723 11.6837 15.6408 22.5884 33.9782 32.2985 32.1805 Green
2 5.4430 6.1158  9.8344 14.7719 23.2234 34.1247 32.0722 32.4367 Dry
3 4.5048 7.7364 11.9494 15.7740 22.6291 33.7642 32.4599 32.5217 Conifer
4 5.3120 6.9558  9.8344 14.3223 22.8088 34.0513 32.2985 32.4045 Snow
5 5.2907 6.6837 10.5367 16.0684 22.6291 33.7156 32.1650 32.4900 Ice
6 5.3120 6.8131 10.9727 15.7114 22.8088 34.6136 32.4772 32.4367 Soil
```

Thank you all

Comment: give an example of the data, something like `dput(head(test))`

Comment: If you explain in mathematical terms what you are trying to accomplish there may be greater hope that a more efficient strategy will be suggested. Asking the greater audience to guess at the goal for the methods you have chosen is not an optimal approach. Might get small advantage by pre-dimensioning logver or gathering in a list (using lapply) and then using cbind only once.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. I made some modifications. Is that any better?